# Confused with imaginary calculus

Tags: complex-numbers

So $i$ is the complex unit and $n \in \mathbb{N} $.
$$e^{2 \pi \ n \ i} = 1$$

$$1^{2 \pi \ n \ i} = 1$$

$$(e^{2 \pi \ n \ i})^{2 \pi \ n \ i} = e^{-4\pi^2 \ n^2}$$

$$e^{-4\pi^2 \ n^2} \neq 1$$

I’m confused with this, can someone please explain to my where the error is in the equations above, or in my thinking? The more I sit on this problem the less I understand.

Comment: They're not equal. This is because complex exponentiation does not define a single-valued function. What you've done here is found an alternate value for $1^{2\pi n i}$.

Comment: $e^z$ is defined by $1+z+\frac{z^2}{2!}+\cdots$ which is single valued. So $a^z$ is single valued only when $a=e$?

Comment: $a^z=e^{z\log a}$, so can $e^z$ be written as $e^{z\log e}$? But $\log e=1$ or $1+2ni\pi$?

Comment: @Kyson Your last remark is correct. The power series defines a particular selection of values for $e^z$ which happen to form an entire function. But, for example, $e^{1/2}$ has two values, given by the positive and negative square roots of $e$. The negative square root is obtained by taking $\log e = 1+2\pi i$.

Comment: So how should $e^z$ be defined?

Comment: $e^{z \log e}$.

Comment: This is one reason we often define $\exp(z)$ in terms of the power series - to avoid our intuition about exponentiation by using the notation $e^z$. @Kyson

Comment: @Thomas Andrews, do you mean we first define a single-valued function $\exp(z)$ by power series, then define $\log$ as its inverse, which is multi-valued, then define $a^z$ by $\exp(z\log a)$, which is multi-valued. Therefore $e^z=\exp(z \log e)$ is also multivalued?

Comment: No, $e^z$ (or $(e^n)^z$ where $n$ is an integers - is a single-valued function always. $a^z$ is multivalued. @Kyson

Comment: @Thomas Andrews, doesn't that sound a little bit strange? I mean $a^z$ are multivalued except for the special case of $a = e$. Also, it is not consistent with $e^z=e^{z \log e}$. We'll need to say $a^z = e^{z \log a}$ EXCEPT when $a=e$?

Comment: Whoops, I just had a brain fault in the previous comment. It is also true that $e^z$ is multivalued. Was thinking of something else. @Kyson

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exponentiation $x^y$ is generally very tricky in complex numbers. You have to give up at least one of the following:

1. That $x^y$ is a single-valued function.
2. That $x^y$ is continuous
3. That $x^y$ is defined for all $x,y, x\neq 0$.

If you keep (1), then you also have to give up $(x^y)^z = x^{yz}$ as a rule.

The best thing to do is define $x^y$ as a multivalued function. Specifically, define a multivalued $\log x$, and define $x^y = e^{y\log x}$.

If you have a multi-valued $x^y$ then **one** of the values of $1^{2\pi n i}$ **is** $e^{-4\pi^2n^2}$.

If $y$ is rational in reduced form $\frac{p}{q}$ with $p,q\in\mathbb Z$, then $x^y$ has $q$ possible values. In particular, if $y$ is an integer, then $x^y$ has one value.

This is related to the fact that we usually pick the positive square root, but, for example, we can see $4^{1/2}=\pm 2$. In complex numbers, there are four values of $\sqrt[4]{1}=1^{1/4}$, namely, $\pm1, \pm i$.

If $y$ is not a rational number, $x^y$ has infinitely many values.

Answer (score 2):

With complex exponentials, you aren't allowed to say $(a^x)^y=a^{(xy)}$, even for real $a$. You are just showing us a counter-example.

Answer (score 0):

The exponential function is periodic in $\mathbb{C}$, so it's not invertible in $\mathbb{C}$.

The confusion comes from the wrong idea that exists an inverse function  $\log x$ with domain $\mathbb{C}$.  An inverse function of exponential is well defined only if we take as his domain $\{z : -\pi<\mathcal{Im}(z)<\pi\}$ or a suitable [Riemann 
surface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_surface) and so we have no confusion.

In my opinion the confusion expressed in the answer is an example of how ill defined and **confusing** is the concept of multi-valued functions: a function **must** be single-value defined!